# Face identification and recognition without libraries

Tags: image, algorithm, identification

Is there any "step by step guide" on how to do a face recognition and identification without any libraries?

The goal is to receive 60 images and identify who is it in every image, so first we will have to get the info of every person and then, identify they image by image.

it's for an academic research and we are not supposed to use any kind of "external help" for our algorithmy. Any programming language will do. We just need to keep everything simple. What should i research and use to do this kind of software?

Comment: "*it's for an academic research and we are not supposed to use any kind of "external help" for our algorithmy. Any programming language will do.*" - Doesn't asking for help at StackOverflow count as external help?

Answer (score 0):

This [article](http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap1.html) provides basic techniques for image recognition. It uses neural nets to recognize handwritten digits.